# Submitting multiple scores to Scoreloop

Tags: windows-phone-7, scoreloop

I'm making a game for Windows Phone (7.5 + 8) with XNA and we decided to use Scoreloop for leaderboards. At the moment our game has both score result and minor result submitted. We would like to have the possibility to have the leaderboard sorted by either one them, but this seems not to be supported in a straight-forward way. Basically what I want is like in Temple Run: Leaderboard for scores and leaderboard for distance you have run.

I tried making a different mode for the different leaderboards and then submitting the scores in different order to them but Scoreloop doesn't seem to allow multiple score submits at the same time.

Any ideas how I could achieve what I'm trying to do? I couldn't find a solution in the Windows Phone documentation for Scoreloop and I couldn't find anything related to this searching online.